# Accidently stopped some services in svchost

Tags: services, task-manager, svchost

I stopped some of the services in `svchost.exe` in Windows 8 and now I am not able open task manager as it throws error.

When I checked in PowerShell all those services are stopped. Even `services.msc` also showing error. Some services svchost was using all my bandwidth. Now I am not able to start services and enable some of the known services. I tries to enable services using PowerShell also but it is showing access is denied. Run as administrator also showing the same error.

Comment: Some services have dependencies, if they were disabled or set to manuel, until you get the dependencies going first they will try to start then fail because of the dependencies. If you could somehow still get to the event viewer %windir%\system32\eventvwr.msc /s There is a high probablity it would tell.

Comment: Is their a way to restore only svchost services to default. when i checked with windows powershell i am able to find all the services. but some services are stopped. I tried to enable but showing administrative privilage. But not able to run as administrator as same error is coming

Comment: svchost was consuming all my bandwidth so i tried to stop some of services inside it. Now everthing is messed up. Any idea

Comment: Reboot didnt work

Comment: I donot understand why down voted me. As reboot did not work. All basic things i have done. Restarted couple of times.

Answer (score 2):

#### Try rebooting the system

Unless you actually *disable* the service, **the service will run again the next time the system is booted up**. As you only mentioned that you stopped the service, there should be no lasting damage.

`svchost` is the Windows service host. Several different services may use the same `svchost` process. It's generally unwise to randomly stop services unless you know what you're doing.

For more information, see the [official Windows documentation on `svchost.exe`](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-is-svchost-exe).

---

#### If key services are disabled...

Open **Control Panel**>**Administrative Tools**>**Services** and reenable the services that were disabled. If this doesn't work, or if you forgot what services were disabled, **you may need to [repair-install Windows](http://www.maximumpc.com/article/how-tos/how_repair_faulty_windows_installation_without_reformatting)**. This process is essentially an in-place upgrade to the same version of the operating system, and preserves installed apps and personal files while replacing system files with fresh copies. More information can be found in [this Windows Secrets forum post](http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/156974-You-CAN-Repair-Windows-8-%288-1%29-Without-Losing-Everything).

Comment: i will reboot, i thing their is no other alternative.Thank you

Comment: Be sure to hit the "check" below the voting controls if this worked for you. That tells us this answer solved the problem.

Comment: Definetely i will do so

Comment: Reboot doesnot work

Comment: I tried from Administrative tools also but it is showing the same error

Comment: But repair-install windows 8 is required

Comment: In run command if we set execute:msconfig. and restart will it work. Do you have any idea or from ControlPanel- Default Program set prrogram access and computer default. Could u tell whether it works

Answer (score 0):

If you disable **INTENTIONALLY** services like **BITS Background Intelligent Transfer service** and **Application Information**...

For Windows **8/8.1/10.**

reboot into recovery settings by holding shift then click Restart option in power settings or Go to *Settings* > *Update & Security* > *Recovery* > *Advanced* *startup* then **restart**.

If already in there you should see Reset and Troubleshoot, Click *Troubleshoot* > *Advanced Options* > *Startup Settings*. Press **6** to reboot into *Safe mode with Command prompt*.

Activate your **superuser** account...

If you are already in a Command Prompt Administrator type

*net user administrator /active:yes*

then exit command prompt and sign out. Note: Don't restart or shutdown

Click the ***Administrator*** account ( if first time using it wait it load into original settings) then open ***Run Command*** Win key + R, then type ***services.msc***

after you open it. It's time to re-enable all the intentional disabled services back to normal. When you are finished exit all windows and restart your PC.

Now go back to your original account and then deactivate the superuser account by opening a Command Prompt (Admin)

*net user administrator /active:no*

That's it

It Occurred to me 2 times and I tested all my skills and knowledge and patience to successfully work it.

BTW... my System is **Windows 10 Home Single Language**